# HDD capacity is larger than external HDD case capability

Tags: hard-drive, boot, external-hard-drive

I purchased an HDD and an external HDD case housing without realizing that external HDD cases have an upper capacity limit. I placed the larger capacity HDD inside the case and formatted to ext4 which displayed its full capacity.

The data inside does not surpass the capability of the external case and when plugged in *after* boot, seems to access files OK. I only now realized my mistake after many months of having boot issues with the external drive and have ordered an appropriate capacity external case.

If the data used on the HDD does not exceed or is not near the capacity of the smaller capacity external drive, what problems can occur? And are there measures I can take to check for corruption, data integrity etc

**EDIT;** Appears from the comments I am not alone in the max capacity revelation. My HDD is a 12Tb WD Gold 3.5" and the external enclosure as stated on the [manufactures website](https://www.lc-power.com/en/product/hddssdm2-enclosures/889cm35/lc-35u3-becrux/) (and not on the site I purchased...) is listed as 10Tb.

As for boot, this is in relation to a linux based media center device, so apologies for the confusion. The device manufactures were the one's who alerted me to this potential issue.

The HDD is about 40% full if it mattered, not including the percentage ext4 uses for inode tables which i never reduced...

Comment: I don't see any issue with having disks with different capacities... Why this is a problem?

Comment: It should work regardless. Sounds like you have a bad disk, not a capacity problem.

Comment: Having "boot issues" suggests that for some reason your external disk is marked as bootable or "active". I doubt very much it is related to capacity. Using `gparted` you should be able to clear the active flag: https://askubuntu.com/a/859714

Comment: What actually happens during boot? It sounds like you need to tell us about that problem rather than telling us you are buying another enclosure. Also it is hard to say more about the capacity issue without you telling us makes and models and how you know this enclosure has an issue with higher capacity disks.

Comment: `without realizing that external HDD cases have an upper capacity limit` .. says who?  Makes and models please.  I own not less than five external enclosures and these mostly just pass through to the USB bus.  I have never heard of such a thing (but still learn every day).

Comment: Depending on the usb chipset in the enclosure, this can happen.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas: Some older enclosures definitely had limits as to the largest sector address they could handle, e.g. I have one which only goes up to 2 GiB (22-bit LBA, I think). The enclosures do have to translate all commands from SCSI (which is used in USB Mass Storage) to ATA (used for the IDE or SATA connection to the disk), so unless the enclosure takes actual SCSI or SAS disks it's always going to be more than "just passthrough"...

Comment: Thank you for the lesson @user1686 .. always learning.  Right as often as I can.  Funny.. I have written USB bidirectional print drivers but the specification for printers don't help me here at all.

Comment: So I finally purchased a known brand whose enclosures have no upper limit. All boot issues have been resolved and even shutdown times have improved. I cannot comment on file integrity as I simply wiped the drive and copied from a backup.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Senor CMasMas said be so kind as to disclose your assumed figure of upper capacity limit. Old hardware may really have one. This is a rare case today. Please disclose your drive capacity as well.

Formating is not enough.
Please ensure you are using a GPT partition table. Any partition under the outdated MBR style partition table will be limited to 2TB size in case of your drive having a sector size of 512 bytes at the interface. That will typically described as **512e/4096** on the spec sheet of the drive.